# Schedule reports based on field change

Tags: apex, reporting, scheduled, analytics

Is there a way to track individual field changes in a visual force page/build a report that shows the fields have not been updated for a while?

All I want to do is keep emailing the user until a field is updated. Is there a simple way to do this?

I am clearly missing something, can someone point to the right direction on how to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm wondering if you can address your requirement via field history tracking. Enable history tracking for the fields of interest and then have a report run off it, which can be emailed (potentially scheduled) to users.

Another possibly way would be to have a workflow fire when any of the fields are updated and then have a task created assigned to the user concerned to remind them to update the fields before a certain date. This however wouldn't apply retrospectively to fields in need of I being updated today.

A third alternative could be field history tracking plus a batch process. So the batch process runs daily and interrogates the history object to check which records on which fields were updated more than a certain time period ago. It then sends emails to the identified records owners.

Comment: I did go through the field history route and created a VF page to show the fields that werent modified over past week.<br/> I am also able to see that I can generate report based of off edit date. I was wondering how will I make it more effective given that I can track only upto 20 fields per object.<br/>

Comment: I have a feeling that the number of fields tracked may be a 'black tab' i.e. increaseable via a case to salesforce support

Comment: You can ask support to increase this, you just need to provide a business reason.